# VLC Player wont display sub or srt subtitles

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I cant have VLC display .sub or .srt subtitles. Neither by naming video and subtitles files the same nor loading the subtitles manually will work. Only if I convert them into ASS or SSA they display with no problem. Why is it that? How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which os and have you tried reinstalling the same or other version of VLC ?

Comment: Works fine here. I've never had a problem displaying subtitles. You need to give us some more information. Operating system? VLC version? Links to example video and srt file that doesn't work?

Comment: I updated to 2.2.1 today and it still wont work. I have Windows 7. As for the video and sub files, I have them on my computer but it could be any because nothing .sub or .srt will work anyway. I have DivX Plus player and the subs display there fine so I dont get it.

Comment: Have you tried older versions?

Comment: Only with the version I had before updating it today. It didnt work either.

Comment: Any help please??